# Android how to call updates child item based on the item from another child as input

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have simple sales management function, I want to record sells and update stock at a time when button clicked, to make it work I have three methods

1: Record sales from which I call two methods "UpdatadeStockAfterSells" and "SaveSalesData" since these two methods depend on fetch data from the database.

2: "UpdatadeStockAfterSells" that update stock in after sells

3: "SaveSalesData" is for recording sales.

"SaveSalesData" is working fine but when I try to update stock app keep on crashing, I really don't know where do I get it wrong.
The concept is "I call two methods inside another method so that they can use some fetch data as their inputs.

```
// for stock       
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("stocks");

//for sales record       
mDatabaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("saleRecords");


 public class recordSalesModel {
     String productName;
     String Quantity;
     public recordSalesModel(){ }

     public recordSalesModel(String productName) {
         this.productName = productName;
     }

     public recordSalesModel(String productName, String quantity) {
         this.productName = productName;
         Quantity = quantity;
     }

     public String getProductName() {
         return productName;
     }

     public void setProductName(String productName) {
         this.productName = productName;
     }

     public String getQuantity() {
         return Quantity;
     }

     public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
         Quantity = quantity;
     }
}
```

// Save sales

```
  public void SaveSalesData(String name, String quantity) {
    recordSalesModel recordSalesModel = new recordSalesModel(name, quantity);
    String uploadId = mDatabaseReference1.push().getKey();
    mDatabaseReference1.child(uploadId).setValue(recordSalesModel, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error : "+ databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), " successful Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

// Update stock

```
 public void UpdatadeStockAfterSells(String ChildKey, String quantity_sold, String stock_Remaining_Quantity, String Stock_Quantity) {
    double NewRemainingStock = Double.valueOf(stock_Remaining_Quantity) - Double.valueOf(quantity_sold);
    double NewRemainingStockPercentage = (Double.valueOf(NewRemainingStock) / Double.valueOf(Stock_Quantity)) * 100;

    mDatabaseReference.child(ChildKey).child("percentageRemain").setValue(String.valueOf(NewRemainingStockPercentage), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error : ==> "+databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
        mDatabaseReference.child(ChildKey).child("remainingQuantity").setValue(String.valueOf(NewRemainingStock), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error : ==> "+databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), " UPDATED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

// Method to record sell

```
public void RecoredSales() {
    final String spiner_seleceted_name = areaSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    final String Selling_Quantity = quantity.getText().toString();

        mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("productName").equalTo(spiner_seleceted_name).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String stockRemainingQuantity = areaSnapshot.getValue(UploadStockModel.class).getRemainingQuantity();
                    String stockQuantity = areaSnapshot.getValue(UploadStockModel.class).getQuantity();
                    String KeyDb = areaSnapshot.getKey();

                     SaveSalesData(spiner_seleceted_name, Selling_Quantity );


                      UpdatadeStockAfterSells(KeyDb, Selling_Quantity, stockRemainingQuantity, stockQuantity);
                    }}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is crashing displaying what message?

Comment: @AlexMamo am testing on smartphone so i get no any error message

Comment: You are getting in the logcat.